# Difference between DHCP options 'Domain-Name' and 'Domain-Search'

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, dhcp, domain-name

What is the difference between the two?

I had thought that domain-name would put the client on the specified domain (ie. If the domain-name was set to "foo.bar" the clients FQDN would be 'hostname.foo.bar'), but http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options seems to imply that both options ('Domain-Name' and 'Domain-Search') simply specify a search domain.

If domain-name does not set the domain for the client, what option would?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `domain-name` option specifies the client's domain name (of which there can only be one), and is specified in [`resolv.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) with the `domain` keyword. This is the domain which will be used when running `hostname -f` on the client.

The `domain-search` option specifies a list of domains to use when looking up bare hostnames, and is specified in `resolv.conf` with the `search` keyword. If this option isn't provided it defaults to the single domain provided by `domain-name`.

Comment: A valid value is .local or maybe .company.com. The default of naked lookups is usually fine.